# Netsuite Error INVALID_KEY_OR_REF

Tags: php, netsuite

Getting this error Invalid custrecord_lt_partner reference key 225399. While trying to insert into

The first two fields are lists/records & the third field is free form text.

Netsuite with Admin rights

Here is the code

```
global $nsClient;

$recordTypeRef = array("internalId" => 91);

$partnerName = "225399";
$companyName = "20562";
$labAcctNum  = "7182794";

$partnerNameFields = new nsComplexObject('SelectCustomFieldRef');

$partnerNameFields->setFields(
    array(
        'value'         => new nsListOrRecordRef(array('internalId' => $partnerName)),
        'internalId'    => 'custrecord_lt_partner' 
    )
);

$companyNameFields = new nsComplexObject('SelectCustomFieldRef');

$companyNameFields->setFields(
    array(
        'value'         => new nsListOrRecordRef(array('internalId' => $companyName)),
        'internalId'    => 'custrecord_lt_company' 
    )
);


$labAcctNumFields = new nsComplexObject('StringCustomFieldRef');

$labAcctNumFields->setFields(
    array(
        'internalId' => 'custrecord_lt_user_lab_acct_number',
        'value'      => $labAcctNum, 
    )
);


$customRecordFields = array(
    "recType"           => $recordTypeRef,
    "customFieldList"   => array($partnerNameFields, $companyNameFields, $labAcctNumFields),
);


$customRecord = new nsComplexObject('CustomRecord');

$customRecord->setFields($customRecordFields);

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($customRecord); echo "</pre>"; exit;


$addResponse = $nsClient->add($customRecord);

if($addResponse->isSuccess) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r("Success"); echo "</pre>"; exit;
}
else {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($addResponse->statusDetail[0]->message); echo "</pre>"; exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this error when the internalID specified does not exist. So I assume that the value of $partnerId is "225399".
Did you double check in Netsuite that an entry with that ID exists? (The URL or the System Tab usually tells you more. Alongside SelectFields there's usually also a Javascript array where you can find the IDs).

Comment: Thanks but I was using the old library, now I am using the new PHP Toolkit and got everything working. But to answer your question yes i was referencing to the wrong internal id

Answer (score 0):

Is $partnerName the entityId field from the partner record, or the internalId field?

You need to supply either an internalId or externalId. Your use of the word "name" within your variable makes me think you are not using internal or external Id.