# How can I insert Sales Order Item with PC unit at Netsuite Using Phptoolkit?

Tags: php, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, php-toolkit

I've been trying to insert Sales Order Item With Same product but with different UOM, PC and Case. The problem is, It only accept Case Unit.

here's the image. [image: netsuite item with units]

In Phptoolkit to define what's the item unit to be set, would be like this.

```
$soi = new SalesOrderItem();
$soi->item->internalId = $internal_id;
$soi->quantity = $q;
$soi->units = new RecordRef();
$soi->units->internalId = $unit_internal_id;
$soi->rate = $rate;
```

Example The units Type 'CSx6' internal id is 5
if i set the internal id 5 for the unit internal id.
then it will accept it and show CSx6 at netsuite.
but the problem is when I try to transfer the item with the BASE UNIT as PC . I just hardcoded the internal ID as 1 because it is a PC.
and I get an error of INVALID_KEY_OR_REF.

So how can I insert the SalesOrderItem with the base unit?

UPDATE:
 I just need to set the internal Id of that unit. the problem is I can't use the Base unit, I want to use PC, But phptoolkit just give me the internal id of unit Type, stock unit, purchase unit, and sales unit. but the base unit is missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netsuite Error INVALID\_KEY\_OR\_REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256994/netsuite-error-invalid-key-or-ref)

Comment: try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256994/netsuite-error-invalid-key-or-ref

Comment: yah I know what's the cause, I just need to set the internal Id of that unit. the problem is I can't use the Base unit, I want to use PC, But phptoolkit just give me the internal id of unit Type, stock unit, purchase unit, and sales unit. but the base unit is missing